# pandas comma separated hierarchy groupby sum

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, hierarchical-data, multi-index

I have the following data format of hierarchical data. There can be multiple rows of a single level and variable depth. I am trying to get the a result where in col_2 we see the aggregated sum of all the inferior levels of the instance.

Using a simple groupby does not work as it does not understand the hierarchical structure. I have tried splitting col_1 into multiple columns named level-1 to level-6 (depth), and consequently groupby level-1 to level-6, but the results are still incorrect in spite of dataframe being multi-index.

code before separation:
`df.groupby(["col_1"], as_index=False).sum()`

code after separation:
`df.groupby(["level-1","level-2","level-3","level-4","level-5","level-6"], as_index=False).sum()`

Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE thanks to @Yo_Chris so far:

````
import pandas as pd
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['PUU', 'PUU;UT', 'PUU;UT', 'PUU;UT;AHU', 'PUU;UT;AHU;CSP', 'PUU;AS', 'PUU;PREV', 'PUU;TECHNOLOGY', 'PUU;TECHNOLOGY', 'PUU;TECHNOLOGY;SPEC'],
                  'Col2': [1000,1000,50,500,250,100,1000,300,500,900]})

# groupby, sum and invert 
s = df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].sum()[::-1]
# groupby, cumsum and invert
s.groupby(s.index.str[0]).cumsum()[::-1])```

# this results in the following:

Col1
PUU                    5600
PUU;AS                 4600
PUU;PREV               4500
PUU;TECHNOLOGY         3500
PUU;TECHNOLOGY;SPEC    2700
PUU;UT                 1800
PUU;UT;AHU              750
PUU;UT;AHU;CSP          250
Name: Col2, dtype: int64
````

While what we want is:

```
PUU                    5600
PUU;AS                  100
PUU;PREV               1000
PUU;TECHNOLOGY         1700
PUU;TECHNOLOGY;SPEC     900
PUU;UT                 1800
PUU;UT;AHU              750
PUU;UT;AHU;CSP          250
```

Comment: why is `a;b` in your expected out 1800 and not 1750? And why is `g;h` 900 and not 800?

Comment: because there are 2 instances of a;b = 1000 + 50 , plus a;b;c and a;b;c;d 500+250 = 1800. Similarly, g = 2 isntances of g + g;h = 300+500+900 = 1700 because h here is a child of g.

Comment: Got it, I was taking the difference not adding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this eventually by splitting col_1 to separate columns per depth. then group by each column (depth 1, 2,..6) and concatenation of all resulting dataframes. Not very clean but it works correctly!

Answer (score 1):

I have made some assumptions based on your sample data. That col1 is always a single character separated by a semicolon and that col1 is always sorted: col1 cannot be `['a;b;c', 'a', 'a;b'...]`

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['a', 'a;b', 'a;b', 'a;b;c', 'a;b;c;d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'g;h'],
                  'Col2': [1000,1000,50,500,250,100,1000,300,500,900]})

# groupby, sum and invert 
s = df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].sum()[::-1]
# groupby, cumsum and invert
s.groupby(s.index.str[0]).cumsum()[::-1]

# return a pd.Series

Col1
a          2800
a;b        1800
a;b;c       750
a;b;c;d     250
e           100
f          1000
g          1700
g;h         900
Name: Col2, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi There, thanks for the reply! could this code be modified to work on data where col_1 is not single characters but actual words separated by ";"? Could you also please explain how this solution works?

Comment: @AliAdiby sure, it can be modified to work where col1 is not a single character but I need more information. Please update your question with new sample data (not an image but how I created my frame). All the code does right now is group on col1, get the sum of each group and invert the frame. Then, the second line, groups the newly formed series on the first character, gets the cumulative sum of each group then inverts the series back to normal.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look again Chris. I have updated the sample in the question update

Comment: I am a little confused by your expected output...My assumption would be that PUU is the parent so why do you not want to cumsum everything? Your expected output treats the second element as the parent. Is that how you want to sum everything (based on the second element in the list)

Comment: Also, can you have a third element listed without the second? `PUU;UT` followed by `PUU;AHU` followed by `PUU;UT;AHU;CSP`

Comment: That's because the tree can have multiple nodes and branches. In my examle the tree structure PUU is de global parent(hierarchy depth 0) and it has 3 children: UT, AS, PREV (all 3 are hierarchy depth 1). UT has its own child (depth 2) being AHU. AHU has its own child: CSP (depth 3). The sum needs to aggregate the sum of all depth below its own depth under its own node.

So PUU is the global parent and is sum of everything. UT is the parent of AHU and AHU the parent of CSP, so the sum of UT : must be that of UT, UT;AHU and UT;AHU;CSP